# How to direct Siri search on iOS to open a PWA instead of in Safari?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps

After adding a PWA to my homescreen, I would like to be able to find the app quickly using Siri.

When I search for my app's name in Siri, it shows the installed PWA under "Applications", however clicking on the icon takes me to the PWA website in Safari rather than launching the PWA application with the correct local context as a standalone application.

Comment: This question was also asked on https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114182